# Imputing the range of values with median

Tags: python, pandas

I have column 'X' in a dataframe. I want to impute the negative values and value above 10 with median.

Below is my sample data

```
index   X
0    -3
1     5
2     7
3     6
4     0
5     8
6     6
7    -2
8     9
9     2465
```

Below is the code that I have tried:

```
median = df.loc[(df['X']<10) & (df['X']>=0), 'X'].median()
df.loc[(df['X'] > 10) & (df['X']<0), 'X'] = np.nan
df['X'].fillna(median,inplace=True)
```

There is still no change in 'X' column even after applying the above codes.

Comment: Do you need median of all values or of filtered values?

Comment: @ jezrael , I need median of fitted values (i.e excluding negative values and values above 10 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) if need median of filtered values:

```
mask = (df['X']<10) & (df['X']>=0)
df['X'] = df['X'].where(mask, df.loc[mask, 'X'].median())
print (df)
   X
0  6
1  5
2  7
3  6
4  0
5  8
6  6
7  6
8  9
9  6
```

Or `median` of all values:

```
mask = (df['X']<10) & (df['X']>=0)
df['X'] = df['X'].where(mask, df['X'].median())
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use:

```
df.loc[(df['X'] > 0) & (df['X'] < 10), 'X'] = df['X'].median()
```